# how to print values in console using scriplet in javascript while a function is called

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

How to print values in console (like `System.out.println()` in `java`) using `scriplet` in `javascript` while a function is called ? if i used `System.out.println("test")` in `scriplet` the values is getting printed while a `jsp` form is loading but i want it to print only when a java script is called.

Comment: you can use console.log(""); for client side logging. And if required you can log errors using the link above. Otherwise i am afraid simple logging from client side to server site cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 System.out.println ("test");
```

That is java and you cannot execute that on client side.

You might looking for

```
console.log("");
```

And while page loading it's printing because the jsp you are submitting processing on server side and java code executes there.

Comment: thnx for the quick response,but this can only be user with browser but i want to print console in my server log file

Comment: No ,you cannot.You should log the user activity on server side. Not with what he is doing on client side. Probably you need that link which Lakshmi added in comments

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
console.log('Hello World!');
```

Comment: This does not print anything in the console if you write it in the jsp. This can only work in JS.